# BIRT in eclipse `Version: 2022-09 (4.25.0)` running in Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS getting error

Tags: java, eclipse, birt

I wanted to create a Simple Listing Report using BIRT

I follow the steps below

> File ->  New -> Others -> Business Intelligence and Reporting Tools -> Report

When I fill up the importanteinformation and click `Finish` I get the error and the below stack trace

How to fix this error?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.ui.ide was unable to load class org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.ui.ReportPerspective.
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.registry.PerspectiveDescriptor.createFactory(PerspectiveDescriptor.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.createPerspective(WorkbenchPage.java:4087)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busySetPerspective(WorkbenchPage.java:3994)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.lambda$10(WorkbenchPage.java:3954)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.setPerspective(WorkbenchPage.java:3954)
    at org.eclipse.ui.wizards.newresource.BasicNewProjectResourceWizard.replaceCurrentPerspective(BasicNewProjectResourceWizard.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.ui.wizards.newresource.BasicNewProjectResourceWizard.updatePerspective(BasicNewProjectResourceWizard.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.ui.ide.wizards.NewReportProjectWizard.updatePerspective(NewReportProjectWizard.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.ui.ide.wizards.NewReportProjectWizard.performFinish(NewReportProjectWizard.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:833)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.lambda$0(Dialog.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener$1.widgetSelected(SelectionListener.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:5796)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1529)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:5025)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:4477)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:823)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.NewProjectAction.run(NewProjectAction.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.views.helpers.EmptyWorkspaceHelper$1.linkActivated(EmptyWorkspaceHelper.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.AbstractHyperlink.handleActivate(AbstractHyperlink.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.AbstractHyperlink.handleMouseUp(AbstractHyperlink.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.AbstractHyperlink.lambda$3(AbstractHyperlink.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:5796)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1529)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:5025)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:4477)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:643)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1440)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.ui.ide was unable to load class org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.ui.ReportPerspective.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:920)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.registry.PerspectiveDescriptor.createFactory(PerspectiveDescriptor.java:79)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.ui.lib (525).
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:335)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:397)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass0(BundleLoader.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:416)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:920)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.ui.views.ElementAdapterManager.<clinit>(ElementAdapterManager.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.ui.preferences.PreferenceFactory.getPreferences(PreferenceFactory.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.ui.preferences.PreferenceFactory.getPreferences(PreferenceFactory.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.ui.ReportPlugin.start(ReportPlugin.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$2.run(BundleContextImpl.java:818)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$2.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:810)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:371)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:605)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:335)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:397)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.MultiSourcePackage.loadClass(MultiSourcePackage.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass0(BundleLoader.java:496)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:416)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.ui.IDEReportPlugin.start(IDEReportPlugin.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$2.run(BundleContextImpl.java:818)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$2.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:810)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:371)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:605)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:335)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:397)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass0(BundleLoader.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:416)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:920)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.registry.PerspectiveDescriptor.createFactory(PerspectiveDescriptor.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.createPerspective(WorkbenchPage.java:4087)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busySetPerspective(WorkbenchPage.java:3994)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.lambda$10(WorkbenchPage.java:3954)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.setPerspective(WorkbenchPage.java:3954)
    at org.eclipse.ui.handlers.ShowPerspectiveHandler.openPerspective(ShowPerspectiveHandler.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.handlers.ShowPerspectiveHandler.lambda$1(ShowPerspectiveHandler.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.ui.handlers.ShowPerspectiveHandler.openOther(ShowPerspectiveHandler.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.ui.handlers.ShowPerspectiveHandler.execute(ShowPerspectiveHandler.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:97)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:195)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.perspectiveswitcher.PerspectiveSwitcher.selectPerspective(PerspectiveSwitcher.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.perspectiveswitcher.PerspectiveSwitcher.lambda$3(PerspectiveSwitcher.java:312)
    at org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener$1.widgetSelected(SelectionListener.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:252)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Error starting module. osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.ui.lib"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="4.4.2.v201410272105"; singleton:="true" [id=525]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:614)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:117)
    ... 117 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/runtime/IPluginDescriptor
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3373)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3578)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:2271)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.loadBundleActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:801)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:753)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:371)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:605)
    ... 120 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.IPluginDescriptor cannot be found by org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.ui.lib_4.4.2.v201410272105
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.generateException(BundleLoader.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass0(BundleLoader.java:536)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:416)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 129 more
```

Comment: It is looking for an `IPluginDescriptor` interface which was removed from Eclipse quite some time ago - that version of Birt is not compatible with recent versions of Eclipse

Comment: @greg-449 is there an available version of `BIRT` i can install that is compatible with this version of eclipse ? or what version of eclipse should i have to be compatible with this `BIRT`

Comment: I don't know much about BIRT, but their site is [here](https://eclipse.github.io/birt-website/) and appears to have up to date builds.